# What is the difference between a "gerund" and a "true noun"?

Tags: nouns, gerunds, ing

[Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/-ing#English) shows this:

> **-ing**
>
> Used to form nouns or noun-like words (or elements of noun phrases) from verbs, denoting the act of doing something, an action, or the embodiment of an action.
>
> - As true nouns.
>
>   - My hearing is not good.
>   - I have had several meetings with him.
> - As gerunds.
>
>   - Smoking is bad for your health.
>   - She has a habit of sleeping late.
>   - I like meeting people.
>
> Used to form nouns denoting materials or systems of objects which are used or employed in an action, or considered collectively.
>
> - Roofing is material that is used to roof.
> - Clothing is material with which one is clothed.
> - The piping is a system of pipes considered collectively.

What is the difference between these 3 examples? Why is "Smoking is bad" the smoking a gerund and not a noun? The true noun makes sense to me, but at the same time what is that, how does it compare to the [gerund](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gerund)? The last one is also a noun, how does that compare to a gerund? How/why is a gerund not a noun?

[It](https://www.grammarly.com/blog/gerund/) says a gerund "is a verb that’s acting as a noun... but it doesn’t stop being a verb...". But it still functions as a verb in some ways? I don't follow.

Comment: I am not convinced that the Wikitionary entry is accurate: roofing, clothing and piping appear to be mass nouns. The gerund uses the root form of the verb and adds the suffix -ing". For example, the meaning of the gerund "thinking" is "the action of the verb "to think"."

Comment: Two similarities between gerunds and verbs is that they can take direct objects and be modified by adverbs: "Smoking cigarettes daily is bad for your health."

Comment: While I don't see the difference much, the end is the same: nouns. Smoke is bad for your health, too.

Comment: Forget the term 'gerund'. All you need to know is whether the word is a verb or noun. But there are cases of ambiguity: in, for example, "Smoking is bad for your health", "smoking" is ambiguous between a verb and a noun, though verb preferred. Noun interpretation can be forced by adjectival premodification, as in "Even occasional smoking is bad for you".

Comment: Let's forget both 'gerund' and 'subjunctive', then. They're both troublesome remnants of previous universes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 1. Smoking is bad for your health.
> 2. Clothing is material with which one is clothed.

The difference between these two should be obvious if you try to add an object to the verbs "smoke" and "clothe":

> 3. Smoking **cigarettes** is bad for your health.
> 4. Clothing **people** is material with which one is clothed.

(3) makes perfect sense, because "smoking" is here being used just as a form of the verb "to smoke." (4) does not make any sense, because "clothing" here is not being used as a form of the verb "to clothe."

Of course, you *can* use "clothing" as a gerund of "to clothe," but this is quite uncommon:

> Clothing the poor is an important way to help them.

Comment: From [Collins](https://grammar.collinsdictionary.com/easy-learning/what-type-of-noun-is-made-from-the-ing-form-of-a-verb#:~:text=The%20%2Ding%20form%20of%20a%20verb%2C%20i.e.%20the%20present%20participle,of%20the%20brakes%20terrified%20me.): <<The -ing form of a verb, i.e. the present participle, can be used as a noun. This type of noun is a verbal noun and it can be used in all the places that a noun can be used, but still keeps some characteristics of the verb. It is sometimes called the gerund.
_The screaming of the brakes terrified me_...>> 'Gerund' is ill-defined. See JL's comment above.

Comment: How does one analyse say 'He has developed the disturbing habit of snoring'?

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I avoided bringing up verbal nouns because "clothing" here isn't a verbal noun either. A verbal noun would be: "His clothing of impoverished people in the city demonstrated his generous character."

Comment: (This usage is very awkward since we typically use "clothing" in the ordinary noun sense, not as a gerund or verbal noun.)